# How can I use compareTo()'s functionality in SQLite?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I am trying to perform a query in an SQLite database to see if some String falls within the range of two fields' values. I have two fields, `start_time` and `end_time` whose values are stored as a String text (not Timestamp) of a format HH:MM and I am getting time in JavaScript of the same format (HH:MM) as a string as well. I want to check if the value I am getting from JavaScript is falling between some record's `start_time` and `end_time` values.

How do I perform that test in an SQL statement? I came across the method `compareTo()` in other languages (Java specifically), which returns a positive, 0 or negative depending which of two strings is greater (alphabetically), and I was hoping I could use the same method if it has an equivalent in SQLite. How can I implement it or how else can I make that check?

Answer (score 1):

As you are dealing with an acceptable time string :-

> ```
> Time Strings
> A time string can be in any of the following formats:
>
> YYYY-MM-DD
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
> HH:MM
> HH:MM:SS
> HH:MM:SS.SSS
> now
> DDDDDDDDDD
> ```
>
> [SQL As Understood By SQLite - Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

then in the case you mention, you can use the **`time`** function which will understand/recognise the time. You can use operators along with a WHERE clause.

### For example

Assuming a table called times is created based upon :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS times;
CREATE TABLE times (start_time TEXT, end_time TEXT);
INSERT INTO times VALUES
    ('12:15','12:36'),
    ('13:26','17:50'),
    ('11:56','13:02'),
    ('10:45','12:10')
;
```

which would look like :-

[image]

Then :-

```
SELECT * FROM times WHERE time(start_time) >= time('11:00') AND time(end_time) <= ('17:00');
```

Would find times that start at or after 11:00 **and** end on or before 17:00.

The results, if applied to the example table, would be :-

[image]

i.e.

- **12:15 - 12:36** starts after **11:00** and ends before **17:00**, so is included.
- **13:26 - 17:50** although starting after **11:00** does not at or before **17:00** so is excluded.
- **11:56 - 13:02** will be included.
- **10:45 - 12:00** does not start before **11:00** so is excluded.